# Not Draw Nothing

Tags: android, opengl-es

I use these functions to draw elements in android using OpenGL-ES. First in the constructor after binding the buffer (that is bind correctly because using GL10 the are drawn) I create the program using the `CreateProgram` function and then I call Draw. I think that the problem is in the draw function. Can anyone tell to me what my mistakes are?

PS: I don't post the code for the binding of buffers because as i said using G10 they are drawn. Now I want to use GL20 because maybe I'm wrong but reading for examples different questions and some pages on android developer site OpenGL-ES is faster because it uses static functions.

Here there is the code thanks indeed :

```
private final String vertexShader="" +
            "attribute vec3 vertex; \n" +
            "void main(){\n" +
            "   gl_Position=vertex;\n" +
            "}";

private final String fragmentShader="" +
            "attribute vec4 colors;\n" +
            "void main(){\n" +
            "   gl_FragColor=colors;\n" +
            "}";


public int LoadShader(String shader,int type){
    int sha= GLES20.glCreateShader(type);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(sha,shader);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(sha);
    return sha;
}

int program=0;
public void CreateGLProgram()
{
    program=GLES20.glCreateProgram();

    GLES20.glAttachShader(program,LoadShader(vertexShader,GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER));
    GLES20.glAttachShader(program,LoadShader(fragmentShader,GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER));

    GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
}

public void DrawShader(){
    GLES20.glUseProgram(program);

    int vertex_handle=GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program,"vertex");
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vertex_handle,3,GLES20.GL_FLOAT,false,4,coordinatesbuff);

    int frag_handle=GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program,"colors");
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(frag_handle,4,GLES20.GL_FLOAT,false,4,colorbuffer);

    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES,indicies.length,GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,indiciesbuffer);

    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertex_handle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(frag_handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have attributes in a fragment shader. If you want per-vertex colors in the fragment shader, you have to define this attribute in the vertex shader and pass the data to the fragment shader in a `varying`.

Additionally, you should check whether your shaders are compiling (`glGetShaderiv(..., GL_COMPILE_STATUS...` and linking (`glProgramiv(..., GL_LINK_STATUS...`) correctly. This would have brought you on the right track since using a attribute in a fragment shader should trigger a compile error. Also `glGetError` should be checked.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what BDL wrote:

You should enable attribute pointers using glEnableVertexAttribArray(int index):

```
int vertex_handle=GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "vertex");
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertex_handle);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vertex_handle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 4, coordinatesbuff);

int frag_handle=GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "colors");
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(frag_handle);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(frag_handle, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 4, colorbuffer);
```